# Wash your hands before you go to sleep. (sleep is a noun or a verb?)

Tags: prepositions, to-infinitive, idioms-in-context

> Wash your hands before you go to sleep.

'sleep' is a noun or a verb in the sentence above? (In other words, the 'to' is a preposition or an infinitive?)

Comment: *go to sleep* is an idiom which means to begin sleeping. See Merriam Webster.

Comment: @Lambie Thx. What's the identity of 'to' though?

Comment: Idioms are generally not broken down. to there is an infinitive marker. as in: begin to sleep.

Comment: @BEBYGONES "To" belongs to the word class (part of speech) **subordinator** and its function here is **marker** of the VP "to sleep".

Comment: Syntactically, it's ***ambiguous***. We could conflate ***to sleep*** with *... **to bed, ...to the land of Nod***, in which case it's preposition + noun. Or we could see it as being the same as *Wash your hands before going **to answer the phone***, in which case it's "infinitive marker" + verb. But it makes no difference to the meaning, so I don't see much point in trying to make a decision.

Comment: Personally, I think the differentiation between preposition 'to' and and infinitive 'to' is very very impoartant in English language.

Comment: @BEBYGONES: So you'll have to spend time thinking about the difference between ***to*** in *I must go to work, I must get to work, I must set to work*, even in contexts where all three utterances mean *exactly* the same thing. I'm glad I don't have to! :)

Comment: @BEBYGONES I disagree. The difference is very important to the grammar of the clause, something you ask about quite often

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wish I had been born in English-speaking countries or had gone to school there. And I think if someone says some words, phonetic values(sounds) have their each value to make meaning. That's why I put some weight on the difference: to infinitive and preposition to

Comment: I don't think it's logically possible to come up with a "minimal pair" utterance where the only thing that distinguishes one meaning from another turns on whether ***to*** is a preposition or an infinitive marker. After all, most native Anglophones probably wouldn't have a clue what prepositions and infinitive markers are in the first place, but they manage to understand English perfectly well! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That's true because English is their first language.

Comment: I would hope people wash their hands before going to bed, unless they have a sink in their bedroom right next to the bed.

Comment: BEBYGONES: I can only imagine the reason you might think it's important to know whether any given occurrence of ***to*** is a preposition or an infinitive marker is because that tells you whether the *next* word is a noun or a verb. But surely it's easier to identify whether it's a noun or a verb *first*, and use that to decide how to classify ***to***. Except that's unnecessary with ***go to sleep***, because it means the same regardless of whether ***sleep*** is a noun or a verb, so you don't need to do *anything* special to understand those words (and *understanding* is all that matters).